# Where are OneDrive offline files stored on galaxy s8?

Tags: onedrive

I offlined synced a folder using OneDrive, trying to find it's physical location on the device storage. I wasn't able to locate it browsing through the dozens of folders on the device.

Answer (score 3):

The offline files are cached in folders using the path:

> `/android/data/user/0/com.microsoft.skydrive/no_backup/stream​_cache/userid......`

source: [OneDrive local cache on Android](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odwork-odedit/onedrive-local-cache-on-android/77b8fbbf-bc16-4682-bf3b-5fc35e476a6b?auth=1)

Comment: Offline files are not there

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work. I don't have a user folder nor a no_backup folder on my phone